# how i can create pricing tab add to cart url?

Tags: magento-1.9, addtocart, pricing

How I can create pricing tab add to cart url ?

I have create 1 product for add to cart url and my product id is 86 
and my Purchase Button url is `/checkout/cart/add/product/id/86`
but when I click to button my cart show no product in cart 
please tell me how I can create add to cart button url ?

[image: image of pricing tab][image: image of checkout]

Answer (score 0):

As per your screenshot and this snap `/checkout/cart/add/product/id/86` , one way to add this product into cart is this, you need add manually add product to cart.

For example click on `purchase` button , on this click you get product id and pass this id on one controller action through ajax call something like.

```
<?php $sucessUrl = Mage::getUrl('yourmodule/controller/action'); ?>
        jQuery.ajax({
            dataType : 'json',
            type: "POST",
            url: "<?php echo $sucessUrl; ?>",
            data: {product_id: id},
            success: function(data) {
                if(data.success == "1"){
                    window.location.replace(data.checkout_url);
                }else{
                    alert('Error !! In Process');
                }
            }
        });
```

now in your controller,

```
$productId = $_POST['product_id'];

        //echo "<pre>";print_r($productIds);die;
        $cart = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart');

            $product = new Mage_Catalog_Model_Product();
            $product->load($productId);
            $params = array(
                'product' => $productId,
                'qty' =>1,
                'sku' => ($product->getSku()) ? $product->getSku() : ''
            );
            $cart->addProduct($product, $params);
            $cart->setIsActive(1);
            $cart->save();

            Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->setCartWasUpdated(true);
            $message = $this->__('%s was successfully added to your shopping cart.', $product->getName());
            Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->addSuccess($message);


            $this->loadLayout();

            $response = array();
            $response['success'] = 1;
            $response['checkout_url'] = Mage::helper('checkout/cart')->getCartUrl();

            $this->getResponse()->setBody(Mage::helper('core')->jsonEncode($response));
```

so after ajax call complete you redirect to checkout cart page. This is custom addtocart process for your example.

Hop it's help you.